# I'm not able to query a model using flask_sqlalchemy while i can store in it and store and query another model

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In my model, I have two classes `User` and `Contact`. I can store data and retrieve data from `User` class easily but querying `Contact` gives me the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/www/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 732, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.comparator, key)
AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'all'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/www/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 185, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.comparator, key)
  File "/srv/www/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 840, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
  File "/srv/www/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/properties.py", line 266, in _fallback_getattr
    return getattr(self.__clause_element__(), key)
  File "/srv/www/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 738, in __getattr__
    key)
AttributeError: Neither 'AnnotatedColumn' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'all'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/srv/www/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    key)
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Contact.query has an attribute 'all'
```

Can anybody help me out I'm stuck.

Comment: I used dir() to find out the attributes: len(dir(User.query)) = 196 where as len(dir(Contact.query)) = 111

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40084807/edit) the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I added attribute query in one of my model, due to which it was giving the error